# generate report in dajngo with data extracted from the database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need help to make a report with pie charts in django, with data coming from my database. 
If you can help me with the queries and how to do the class, thank you in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Django Report Tools**.
https://django-report-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: this error show: AttributeError: module 'reportlab.graphics.charts' has no attribute 'pie' @EdgarRonda